# Recording Controller shows ocsp digicert and jibberish in body data

Tags: jmeter, ocsp

Can anyone please help me, I see ocsp.digicert.com in IP name and jibberish in Body data when I record script from HTTP Test Script Recorder
Can someone please guide me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLOtr.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's an endpoint for [Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol), I don't think you should be including it into your recording or test execution scope

If you create a test plan [from the Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) comes with some pre-populated URL filters to exclude from recording:

[image]

the stuff like Windows Update, Google Analytics, and so on should be excluded because it will create extra requests which don't have anything in common with the application under test.

So I would recommend adding an entry to exclude this URL from recording, the relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
.*ocsp\.digicert\.com.*
```

if you have some recorded HTTP Request samplers and you're unwilling to re-record - just delete them from the test plan.

Comment: The problem is it only records this and nothing else. So all my relevant calls are not recorded.
If I try Fiddler it records the calls but Jmeter doesn't